# LinkedList - loop not working - Java

Tags: java, linked-list, counter, extend

I am required to write a method that returns a number - the amount of times an element is found in a linked list. So far I have;

```
package Question4;

import net.datastructures.Node;

public class SLinkedListExtended<E> extends SLinkedList<E> {
    // returns the number of occurrences of the given element in the list
    public int count(E elem) {

        Node<E> cursor = tail;
    int counter = 0;

    if ((cursor != null) && (!(cursor.getElement().equals(elem)))) { //tail isnt null and element is not equal to elem 

        cursor = cursor.getNext(); //go to next node

    } else if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getElement().equals(elem))){ //cursor isn't null and element equals elem

        counter++; //increment counter
    }
    else { 
        return counter; //return counter 
    }
    return counter;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    SLinkedListExtended<String> x = new SLinkedListExtended<String>();

    x.insertAtTail("abc");
    x.insertAtTail("def");
    x.insertAtTail("def");
    x.insertAtTail("xyz");
    System.out.println(x.count("def")); // should print "2"
    x.insertAtTail(null);
    x.insertAtTail("def");
    x.insertAtTail(null);
    System.out.println(x.count("def")); // should print "3"
    System.out.println(x.count(null)); // should print "2"
}
}
```

I have extended to a class which compiles correctly, so I know the problem is in my method. I can't figure out what to do, my code returns 0, which is probably the counter integer remaining at 0 and not going through the loop statement. Any ideas are appreciated.

**Edit. SLinkedList code:**

```
import net.datastructures.Node;

public class SLinkedList<E> {
protected Node<E> head; // head node of the list
protected Node<E> tail; // tail node of the list (if needed)
protected long size; // number of nodes in the list (if needed)

// default constructor that creates an empty list
public SLinkedList() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
}

// update and search methods
public void insertAtHead(E element) {
    head = new Node<E>(element, head);
    size++;
    if (size == 1) {
        tail = head;
    }
}

public void insertAtTail(E element) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element, null);
    if (head != null) {
        tail.setNext(newNode);
    } else {
        head = newNode;
    }
    tail = newNode;
    size++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) { // test
    SLinkedList<String> list = new SLinkedList<String>();

    list.insertAtHead("lol");

}
```

}

Comment: You have two separate questions to solve: 1. how to iterate through the list (will depend on what the implementation of the superclass is) and 2. how to count the elements (equals plus incrementing the counter).

Answer (score 0):

The code in `count` is not in a loop, so it'll just return after the first element.

Try this:

```
public int count(E elem) {
    Node<E> cursor = tail;
    int counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if ((cursor != null) && (!(cursor.getElement().equals(elem)))) { //tail isnt null and element is not equal to elem 
            cursor = cursor.getNext(); //go to next node
        } else if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getElement().equals(elem))){ //cursor isn't null and element equals elem
            counter++; //increment counter
        }
        else { 
            return counter; //return counter 
        }
    }
}
```

Also, note that `cursor.getElement().equals(elem)` will return a `NullPointerException` when `cursor.getElement()` is `null`. The easiest way to deal with this is probably to write a separate equals method:

```
boolean equals(E e1, E e2)
{
  if (e1 == null)
    return e2 == null;
  if (e2 == null)
    return false;
  return e1.equals(e2);
}
```

Also, presumably `Node<E> cursor = tail;` makes it point to the end of the list and presumably you want `Node<E> cursor = head;` instead.

Comment: Ok, ive done this but it still returns 0. Can you see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I can't see anything else wrong. Did you change all 3 things? Try putting print statements in your function or debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a while loop instead of an if clause

```
**while** ((cursor != null) && (!(cursor.getElement().equals(elem)))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental things that you were missing was a loop. Since you are essentially searching for something, you want to loop through the entire list. Once you run into an element that matches the one that you are searching for, you want to increment the count by 1. Once you have finished looping through the entire list, you want to return that count. So this is my solution. I keep it simple so you could understand:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Duplicates<E> extends LinkedList<E> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duplicates<String> duplicates = new Duplicates<String>();
        duplicates.add("abc");
        duplicates.add("def");
        duplicates.add("def");
        duplicates.add("xyz");
        System.out.println(duplicates.duplicateCount("def"));
        duplicates.add(null);
        duplicates.add("def");
        duplicates.add(null);
        System.out.println(duplicates.duplicateCount("def"));
        System.out.println(duplicates.duplicateCount(null));
    }

    public int duplicateCount(E element) {
        int count = 0;
        for (E e : this) {
            if (e == element) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
2
```

Comment: OP is using a custom `SLinkedList`, not Java's `LinkedList`, so the issue of iteration has to be answered as well (but there is not enough data atm in the question to answer it).

Comment: I'm assuming that the custom LinkedList actually extends LinkedList, so it is still iterable. My method should still work.

Comment: since this is presented as an assignment, I don't think it's probable that it does extend `LinkedList`, but everything is possible.

Comment: Nope, its custom :/ Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Well it would help us if you could post the code of the custom `SLinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you combine Martin's answer (which tells you how to count the elements) with this, which tell you how to be able to use foreach - you just have to make your `SLinkedListExtended` implement `Iterable`, whioch should be something liek the follwoing (you could do this on `SLinkedList`, but I'm assuming you were told not to alter the code for that one):

```
public class SLinkedListExtended<E> extends SLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> () {

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        final Node<E> itHead = head;
        return new Iterator<E>() {

            Node<E> current = itHead;
            long position = 0;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return current != null && position < size;
            }

            public E next() {
                current = current.getNext();
                ++position;
                return current.getElement();
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

        };
    }

};
```

I can't vouch for all the details, but this should cover most of it. You may also consider using `equals` instead of `==`, but don't forget to check the elements for nullity.

`next` should only be called if `hasNext` is `true`, so it's not a problem if it throws an exception (but it should be a `NoSuchElementException` to keep in line with the contract).

Implementing `Iterable` makes your class compatible with the Collections library, hence the support for foreach, but you can use it to do raw iteration by calling `iterator`, `hasNext` and `next` yourself.